# Can I retrieve other public media by media ID using the Instagram Basic Display API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Can I retrieve other public media using the Instagram Basic Display API? Or can I only access the media of authorized users? According to the documentation, it seems like I can retrieve public media from other users if I have the media ID, but I haven't been able to test it myself, so I'm asking for clarification.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-profiles-and-media

I followed link and tested all the steps with reference to.

`/me/media` was called, but APIs called through `mediaId` could not be called except for `17896450804038745` shown in the example.(Include my media)